# Insert/Remove view element in between other View elements in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

how can i add an TextView/Button in between View Elements.

I m Fetching Comments and its replies from Server and if comment has reply then It will show View Reply Button, and when user touch the button, it will fetch Replies for that comments and show Below that comment only., and when user again press replies button, it will get disappear

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/commentScrollLayout"

                    >



                   </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
```

The fetched comments are added in LinearLayout- id-commentScrollLayout, so my question is how can i insert/remove replies for that comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) method on `LinearLayout`. This method takes second parameter - index of position where you want to insert view. Now you need to determine this index based on pressed comment. You can use [indexOfChild](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild%28android.view.View%29) method for that:

```
View pressedComment; // Comment pressed by user.
LinearLayout comments = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.commentScrollLayout); 
// Get index of pressed comment.
int index = comments.indexOfChild(pressedComment);
// Create reply text view.
TextView reply = ..;
// Insert reply after the comment.
comments.addView(reply, index + 1);
```

For removing you can either remove replies by index or, if you saved views somewhere, by views. Check [removeView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) and [removeViewAt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewAt%28int%29).

Comment: thanks Nikita, what will be pressedComment, will it be comment textview id ?

Comment: @SunilLohar no, it will be actual `View` that represents comment. I think you can get it in `onClickListener`.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove and add views with this 2 commands.

```
View.removeView();
View.addView();
```

Get the view by calling

```
findViewById(R.id.yourviewid);
```

Create view in code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

**Example**

Add a view

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewByid(R.id.commentScrollLayout);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setId(1337);
tv.setText("Test");
ll.addView(tv);
```

Remove a view

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewByid(R.id.commentScrollLayout);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewByid(1337);
ll.removeView(tv);
```

OR

make the TextView global and you do not need the id.

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't answer the question. You are explaining how to add/remove views, but the question is regarding adding a view in between other views.

Comment: @zundi The question wasn't clear about the structure of the layout inside the commentScrollLayout. Did you read my answer? Since it looks like he isn't using a relativelayout or constraintlayout my solution probably works.

Comment: Although my solution from almost 6 years ago is ugly. Nowdays I would recommend to use a RecyclerView and to handle the removing and adding of views inside the Adapter. To use a scrollview for that purpose is a terrible idea.